# Symfony 5 and PostgreSQL connections

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL database from a Symfony 5 application, but I get the following error:

**You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.pgsql_entity_manager".**

it is very strange.

The dbal configuration is:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: mysql
    connections:
        mysql:
            url: '%env(DATABASE_URL_MYSQL)%'
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
        pgsql:
            url: 'pgsql://userpost:pass123@127.0.0.1:5432/Taller'
            driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
            server_version: '9.3'
            charset: utf8mb4

orm:
    default_entity_manager: pgsql
    entity_managers:
        mysql:
            connection: mysql
            mappings:
                Main:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: Main
        pg:
            connection: pgsql
            mappings:
                Pg:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/EntityPg'
                    prefix: 'App\EntityPg'
                    alias: Pg
```

Can you help me please ?
Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an entity manager called `pgsql`. You have `pg` and `mysql`. So, change `default_entity_manager: pgsql` to be `default_entity_manager: pg`

Comment: Ohhh thanks thanks, you are right. ... I have another error, but I am going to open a new post. Thanks.